# How can I get convert a 3D point in a HelixToolkit Viewport3DX to a 2D position?

Tags: wpf, helix-3d-toolkit

Simple question with I expect not a very simple answer.

I have a Viewport3DX, and I'd like to be able to convert a point in there, i.e. 0.5, 0.7, 1.2 for x/y/z to a 2D position in the window, taking into account the camera/zoom etc.

Is there a built in way to do this in HelixToolkit/Viewport3DX?

Cheers

Garry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Viewport3DX.Project to project a 3D point to 2D.

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I wanted.